# PDF file gets exlcluded from build files Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

My package.json looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "portfolio",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Udbhav Prasad",
    "license": "MIT",
    "engines": {
        "node": "14.x"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist/UdbhavPrasad-Resume.pdf"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "start": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "three": "^0.128.0",
        "vite": "^2.3.3"
    }
}
```

But when I build it, in /dist is excludes the resume and wont serve it when GET request is sent

Thank you

Comment: Seems relevant ~ https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory

Comment: Struggling with this right now, did you ever figure out a solution? I want Vite to let me include a CNAME file in the base of my dist folder

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way to get your pdf file built is simply to place it at the root of your `/public` folder. That way it would appear at the root of your `/dist` folder once built.

See https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose your HTML look like this:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>PDF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a download="" href="./pdf/UdbhavPrasad-Resume.pdf" class="cv-download">Download CV</a>
        
        <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your main.js file, you can get the URL with `?url`. then set the URL to your preferred place. That's it.

```js
import pdfURL from "../pdf/UdbhavPrasad-Resume.pdf?url";

document.querySelector(".cv-download").href = pdfURL;
```

For more information read this
https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Comment: Please check [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should add [code instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).